# How can I push a new project to my hg mercurial URL?

Tags: mercurial

I have a URL that is storing all of our Repositories at: http://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx

I've created a new project called MyProject1 in Visual Studios.

I open command prompt and did `cd MyProject1`

I did `hg init`

Everything is good.

I then want to push this project to my repository, I do

```
hg add
```

Everything looks good.

I do `hg commit -m "Initial Version"`

Everything looks good.

I do `hg push http://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx`

I get this back:

```
pushing to http://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx
abort: 'http://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx' does not appear to be an hg repository:
---%<--- (text/html; charset=cp1252)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11
DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="/static/hgicon.png" type="image/png" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, nofollow" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style-paper.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/mercurial.js"></script>

<title>Mercurial repositories index</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
<a href="https://mercurial-scm.org/">
<img src="/static/hglogo.png" width=75 height=90 border=0 alt="mercurial" /></a

</div>
<div class="main">
<h2 class="breadcrumb"><a href="/">Mercurial</a> </h2>

<table class="bigtable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><a href="?sort=name">Name</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=description">Description</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=contact">Contact</a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=lastchange">Last modified</a></th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>

---%<---
!
```

What in the world am I doing wrong? Am I missing something trivial here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check that you have a repository at  `http://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx`. based on response it is not. You can always go and change file `.hg/hgrc/default` adding something like

```
[paths]
default = http://bitbucket.org/xxxx/xxx
```

Which would point your default branch to a repo.

Comment: I want to create a new repository on our network URL though, am i missing steps to do that as well?

Comment: Based on HTML you get back, you are hitting a Mercurial serve run via `hg serve` command. So, you can just clone it via `hg clone http://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx somepath` and then take a look at `.hg/hgrc` file in the cloned repo and then use that URL.